# The union of several vectors

Tags: matlab, set

I have three vectors, `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`, each of which has 500 values. The 
three vectors may or may not have the same values. I want to know how 
to get the union set of the three vectors. If they have same values,
the value can only be dislayed once in the union set.

Comment: What's wrong with [`union`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html)? Is there something specific in the documentation that you don't understand? Please show your code and any errors. Also, please read the tag descriptions and only use those that are appropriate. Not everything that starts with "matlab-" will be related to your question.

Comment: @horchler, Matlab union can only combine two vectors at one time. How to combine several vectors at one time?

Comment: Start with two of them. The union is both [associative and commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Algebraic_properties).

Comment: @horchler，any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to the concatenation ([`cat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)) of all vectors. This allows an **arbitrary number of vectors**, using a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) generated from a cell array containing all vectors. All vectors are assumed to have the **same, known orientation** (they are all row vectors, or all column vectors).

```
vectors = {[1 4 3 2], [4 5 6], [5 1 8], [4 8]};  %// row vectors
result = unique(cat(2, vectors{:}));             %// change "2" to "1" for column vectors
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a single call to [`union`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html):

```
% Create random example data
rng(1);
v1  = randi(1000,[1 500]);
v2  = randi(1000,[1 500]);
v3  = randi(1000,[1 500]);

v_union = union([v1(:);v2(:)],v3)
```